# How to compare the difference between two images and return the coordinates of the point

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to find the default location of the CAPTCHA picture slider and get the coordinates of the default location, and I have processed the two images.
images like after
https://i.loli.net/2019/07/31/5d412d6c7d95e29689.png
https://i.loli.net/2019/07/31/5d412d6c7e25770645.png

python3 PIL lib

```py
im1 = Image.open("frame.png")
im2 = Image.open("frame1.png")
diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1).getbbox()
```

(29, 65, 289, 151) is not the result.

Comment: Please explain what you expect the result to be

Answer (score 1):

Try this python code. Image locations will be written to imagePositions.txt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2 
import imutils
import numpy as np  

import argparse
import os, shutil

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-b", "--beforeimage", required=True,
    help="path to first image")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to 2nd image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the example image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
originalImage = image #save copy to use later
beforeimage = cv2.imread(args["beforeimage"])

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
beforeimage = cv2.cvtColor(beforeimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

res = cv2.bitwise_xor(image,beforeimage, mask= beforeimage) 

if os.path.exists("imageDiff.png"):
    os.remove("imageDiff.png")

if os.path.exists("imagePositions.txt"):
    os.remove('imagePositions.txt')

cv2.imwrite('imageDiff.png', res)

image = res

image = (255-image) #invert black and white

# threshold the image (convert it to pure black and white)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# find the contours (continuous blobs of pixels) the image
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Hack for compatibility with different OpenCV versions
contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]

with open('imagePositions.txt', 'w+') as out:
    # Now we can loop through each of the four contours and extract the letter
    # inside of each one
    cntr = 1
    for contour in contours:
        # Get the rectangle that contains the contour
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        #check for needed size here
        if (w > 3 and h > 3 ):
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            #add some surrounding area we require
            y1 = y -20
            if y1 < 0:
                y1 = 0
            h1 = h + 40
            x1 = x - 30
            if x1 < 0:
                x1 = 0
            w1 = w + 60     
            crop_img = originalImage[y1:y1+h1, x1:x1+w1]
            #We have a folder to store cropped images
            cv2.imwrite('ImageDifferences/' + str(cntr) + '.png', crop_img)
            out.write(str(cntr) + '.png : ' + str(x1+w1/2) + ',' + str(y1+h1/2) + '\n')
            cntr = cntr + 1
```

Comment: Looks so complicated, is there an easy way? Today I tried a line to convert the image to L mode, and binarized the image, using the getbbox method in the PIL library to get the coordinates of the point.

Comment: Any way is good (if it works). The idea is to compare two images, get difference and location of the differences. In the script there are steps to cut sections where differences were marked so we can see what was marked as difference and adjust if needed.